# R shiny select part of HTML file by id

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have an application that displays data on indicators. Each indicator (30+) has a definition. We have this definition of all indicators in a single html file (easier to maintain than 30 different ones).

In my ShinyApp, I want to show only the section relevant to the indicator selected, not the full document.

I was wondering how this could be done....

Here is an example that is only showing the full 'document' instead of the part which is selected in the sidebar:

```
documentation <- structure("<div> <div id=\"part1\"> <h1>Part 1</h1> <p>This is part 1 out of 2</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> </div> <div id=\"part2\"> <p>&nbsp;</p> <h1>Part 2</h1> <p>This is part 2 out of 2.</p> </div> </div>", html = TRUE, class = c("html", "character"))
documentation


library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(

    selectInput(inputId = "part",label = "Select the part you want to see", choices = c("part1", "part2"))

  ),
  dashboardBody(

    uiOutput("section")

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$section <- renderUI({

    HTML(documentation) # This needs subsetting based on input$part

  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a quick and dirty solution, by manipulating the HTML as a string.
I wonder if there are more elegant methods though...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(

    selectInput(inputId = "part",label = "Select the part you want to see", choices = c("part1", "part2"))

  ),
  dashboardBody(

    uiOutput("section")

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$section <- renderUI({

    # HTML(documentation)

    t1 <- strsplit(documentation, "<div")[[1]][grepl(input$part, strsplit(documentation, "<div")[[1]])]
    t2 <- paste0("<div", t1)
    t2 <- gsub("</div> </div>", "</div>", t2)
    HTML(t2)

  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```